# subsetting - meaning of "." in R

Tags: r, subset

I have come across this comand

```
unique(StudentGroups[,.(groupID, start, end, student)])
```

I was wondereing what is the purpose of the `.` ?

Comment: It is creating a `list`.  You can replace with `list(groupID, ..`

Comment: Is `StudentGroups` a `data.table`? Otherwise I don't know that `.` is defined. Assuming it is (and just adding clarity and definition to @akrun's comment): from `?data.table`: "The expression `.()` is a *shorthand* alias to `list()`; they both mean the same. (An exception is made for the use of `.()` within a call to `bquote`, where `.()` is left unchanged.)"

Comment: Some discussion of what the `.` can mean can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27560562/2372064. It entirely depends on the context.