# use ggplot() every group applyed group_by()

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, facet-wrap

I use `facet_wrap` to every group plot, 
but I need to save every plot individual and find the under link.

I tried program  the answer in the URL link and can save PDFfile, 
but present the ERROR MASSAGE.

CODE:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  do({
    p <- ggplot(., aes(x =Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
    ggsave(p, filename = paste0("fig/", unique(.$Species), ".pdf"))
  })
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

`Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3`

URL:
[applying a function to the output of dplyr's group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556707/applying-a-function-to-the-output-of-dplyrs-group-by)

Comment: `do` wants you to return a data.frame

Comment: Maybe you want `library(tidyverse);iris %>% 
  split(.$Species) %>%  map(~ggplot(., aes(x =Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point() ) %>% walk2(names(.), ~ggsave(.x, filename = paste0(.y, ".pdf")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can make `do` have a point (or just any data.frame for that matter)

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  do({
    p <- ggplot(., aes(x =Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
    ggsave(p, filename = paste0("fig", unique(.$Species), ".pdf"))
    invisible(.)
  })
```